# GStreamer Python Error: 'gst.ElementNotFoundError: videoconvert'

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, gstreamer

I'm trying to create a simple GStreamer pipeline that takes a video, crops and plays it, **with python.**

Through the terminal, this pipeline works great:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location='/home/inbarcha/Desktop/gstreamer_interface/U2One.mp4' ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videocrop top=150 left=150 right=4 bottom=0 ! ximagesink
```

But, when I try to use this python code:

```
import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class CropVideo:
    def __init__(self, video_path, top_crop, left_crop, right_crop, bottom_crop):
        self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline('crop_video')

        self.filesrc = gst.element_factory_make('filesrc', 'file_src')
        self.filesrc.set_property('location', video_path)
        self.pipeline.add(self.filesrc)

        self.decodebin = gst.element_factory_make('decodebin', 'decode')
        self.pipeline.add(self.decodebin)
        self.filesrc.link(self.decodebin)

        self.videoconvert = gst.element_factory_make('videoconvert', 'convert')
        self.pipeline.add(self.videoconvert)
        self.decodebin.link(self.videoconvert)

        self.videocrop = gst.element_factory_make('videocrop', 'crop')
        self.videocrop.set_property('top', top_crop)
        self.videocrop.set_property('left', left_crop)
        self.videocrop.set_property('right', right_crop)
        self.videocrop.set_property('bottom', bottom_crop)
        self.pipeline.add(self.videocrop)
        self.videoconvert.link(self.videocrop)

        self.ximagesink = gst.element_factory_make('ximagesink', 'output_video')
        self.pipeline.add(self.ximagesink)
        self.videocrop.link(self.ximagesink)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = CropVideo('/home/inbarcha/Desktop/gstreamer_interface/U2One.mp4', 150, 150, 4, 0)
    gtk.main()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/inbarcha/Desktop/gstreamer_interface/src/gstreamer_crop_video.py", line 41, in <module>
    start = CropVideo('/home/inbarcha/Desktop/gstreamer_interface/U2One.mp4', 150, 150, 4, 0)
  File "/home/inbarcha/Desktop/gstreamer_interface/src/gstreamer_crop_video.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.videoconvert = gst.element_factory_make('videoconvert', 'convert')
gst.ElementNotFoundError: videoconvert
```

I can't figure out the problem. 
I've tried to make python use gst-1.0 and not gst-0.10, but although I did download the python package with "sudo apt-get update / sudo apt-get install python-gst-1.0", in the python2.7 dist-packages directory I only see "gst-0.10", and I can't seem to find the installation directory for gst-1.0.

I feel like I'm missing something and the answer is right in front of me.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Ubuntu version: 14.04 
Python version: 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that `videoconvert` element is not available in Gstreamer 0.10. According to this documentation https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/appendix/porting-1-0.html?gi-language=c

> ffmpegcolorspace was removed and replaced with videoconvert

Comment: Thank you - in a C project, I managed to use the gstreamer-1.0 library, and videoconvert indeed worked.